# How to create SPA with Elm 0.19?

Tags: elm, elm-architecture

I am trying to build a SPA with Elm and create three pages, that should show the content, depends on URL.

[image]

The content of these three pages are similar, for example `Page.elm`:

```
module Page.NotFound exposing (Msg(..), content)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)



---- UPDATE ----


type Msg
    = NotFoundMsg


content : Html Msg
content =
    p [] [ text "Sorry can not find page." ]
```

In the `Main.elm`, I have the following code:

```
module Main exposing (Model, Msg(..), init, main, update, view)

import API.Keycloak as Keycloak exposing (..)
import Browser
import Browser.Navigation as Nav
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Json.Decode as Decode
import Page.Account as Account
import Page.Home as Home
import Page.NotFound as NotFound
import Route
import Url
import Url.Parser exposing ((</>), Parser, int, map, oneOf, parse, s, string)



---- MODEL ----


type alias Model =
    { key : Nav.Key
    , url : Url.Url
    , auth : Result String Keycloak.Struct
    }


init : Decode.Value -> Url.Url -> Nav.Key -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init flags url key =
    ( Model key url (Keycloak.validate flags), Cmd.none )



---- ROUTE ----


type Route
    = Account



---- UPDATE ----


type Msg
    = PageNotFound NotFound.Msg
    | PageAccount Account.Msg
    | PageHome Home.Msg
    | LinkClicked Browser.UrlRequest
    | UrlChanged Url.Url


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        LinkClicked urlRequest ->
            case urlRequest of
                Browser.Internal url ->
                    ( model, Nav.pushUrl model.key (Url.toString url) )

                Browser.External href ->
                    ( model, Nav.load href )

        UrlChanged url ->
            ( { model | url = url }
            , Cmd.none
            )



-- SUBSCRIPTIONS


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions _ =
    Sub.none



---- VIEW ----


info : Html Msg
info =
    header [] [ text "Header" ]


createLink : String -> Html Msg
createLink path =
    a [ href ("/" ++ path) ] [ text path ]


navigation : Html Msg
navigation =
    ul []
        [ li [] [ createLink "home" ]
        , li [] [ createLink "account" ]
        ]


content : Model -> Html Msg
content model =
    main_ []
        [ case parse Route.parser model.url of
            Just path ->
                matchedRoute path

            Nothing ->
                NotFound.content
        ]


matchedRoute : Route.Route -> Html Msg
matchedRoute path =
    case path of
        Route.Home ->
            Home.content

        Route.Account ->
            Account.content


body : Model -> List (Html Msg)
body model =
    [ info
    , navigation
    , content model
    ]


view : Model -> Browser.Document Msg
view model =
    { title = "Cockpit"
    , body = body model
    }



---- PROGRAM ----


main : Program Decode.Value Model Msg
main =
    Browser.application
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        , onUrlChange = UrlChanged
        , onUrlRequest = LinkClicked
        }
```

The compiler complains:

```
-- TYPE MISMATCH -------------- /home/developer/Desktop/elm/cockpit/src/Main.elm

The 2nd branch of this `case` does not match all the previous branches:

104|         [ case parse Route.parser model.url of
105|             Just path ->
106|                 matchedRoute path
107|
108|             Nothing ->
109|                 NotFound.content
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
This `content` value is a:

    Html NotFound.Msg

But all the previous branches result in:

    Html Msg

Hint: All branches in a `case` must produce the same type of values. This way,
no matter which branch we take, the result is always a consistent shape. Read
<https://elm-lang.org/0.19.0/union-types> to learn how to “mix” types.

-- TYPE MISMATCH -------------- /home/developer/Desktop/elm/cockpit/src/Main.elm

Something is off with the 2nd branch of this `case` expression:

120|             Account.content
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
This `content` value is a:

    Html Account.Msg

But the type annotation on `matchedRoute` says it should be:

    Html Msg

-- TYPE MISMATCH -------------- /home/developer/Desktop/elm/cockpit/src/Main.elm

Something is off with the 1st branch of this `case` expression:

117|             Home.content
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
This `content` value is a:

    Html Home.Msg

But the type annotation on `matchedRoute` says it should be:

    Html Msg
Detected errors in 1 module.
```

I know that the type is wrong, but do not know, how to prove it.

How can I get it to work?

I also looked at the example from https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-spa-example/blob/master/src/Main.elm but could not figure, how does it work.

Comment: would you share what's going on inside API.Keycloak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple `Msg` types, which is OK, but it can lead to confusion. In short: `Main.Msg` is not the same type as `NotFound.Msg`.

The function `matchedRoute` returns a `Html Main.Msg` while the function `NotFound.content` returns a `Html NotFound.Msg`; completely different types.

You're already 99% of the way there because you have a `PageNotFound NotFound.Msg` type constructor which produces a `Main.Msg`. This allows you to *wrap* the `NotFound.Msg` in a `Main.Msg`. It should be a matter of doing `PageNotFound NotFound.content` in your `Nothing ->` branch.

Comment: The explanation is right, but I don't think the suggestion is. What you need to do in the `Nothing ->` branch, I think, is `NotFound.content |> Html.map PageNotFound`. This will map `Html NotFound.Msg` to `Html Main.Msg` by wrapping `NotFound.Msg` in `PageNotFound` which is of type `Main.Msg`.

Comment: This is what's being done here in elm-spa-example: https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-spa-example/blob/master/src/Main.elm#L71

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `Msg` type referred to by `NotFound.content` is `NotFound.Msg`, the `Msg` type referred to by `Main.matchedRoute` is `Main.Msg`, and these do not unify automatically. So when you use these in different branches of a `case` expression, the compiler will tell you they are different and can't be unified into a single type for the `case` expression to return.

So you have to convert one to the other, and the usual way to do that is to add a variant to the "outer" msg type (`Main.Msg`) that wraps the "inner" msg type (`NotFound.Msg`). Fortunately you've already added that variant as `PageNotFound NotFound.Msg`, so we can move on.

The next step is to do the wrapping of `NotFound.Msg`s in `PageNotFound`s. Unfortunately, we rarely get to handle values of `NotFound.Msg` alone, it's usually wrapped in some other type like `Html` or `Cmd`, which is trickier to deal with. Fortunately, Evan was foreknowing enough to predict this scenario and added `Cmd.map` and `Html.map` for us to use. Just like `List.map` and `Maybe.map`, `Cmd.map` and `Html.map` takes a function `a -> b` and uses it to convert `Html a`s or `Cmd a`s to `Html b`s or `Cmd b`s respectively.

So, all you really need to do here is use `Html.map` with `PageNotFound` on `NotFound.content`:

```
content : Model -> Html Msg
content model =
    main_ []
        [ case parse Route.parser model.url of
            Just path ->
                matchedRoute path

            Nothing ->
                NotFound.content |> Html.map PageNotFound
        ]
```

Both branches will now return `Main.Msg` and the compiler should be happy :)

And btw, in elm-spa-example, this is being done [here](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-spa-example/blob/ad14ff6f8e50789ba59d8d2b17929f0737fc8373/src/Main.elm#L71)