# Is Cmd.map the right way to split an Elm SPA into modules?

Tags: elm

I'm building a single page application in Elm and was having difficulty deciding how to split my code in files.

I ended up splitting it using 1 module per page and have `Main.elm` convert the `Html` and `Cmd` emitted by each page using `Cmd.map` and `Html.map`.

My issue is that the documentation for both Cmd.map and Html.map [says that](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Platform-Cmd#map) :

> This is very rarely useful in well-structured Elm code, so definitely read the section on structure in the guide before reaching for this!

I checked the only 2 large apps I'm aware of :

1. elm-spa-example uses Cmd.map (https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-spa-example/blob/cb32acd73c3d346d0064e7923049867d8ce67193/src/Main.elm#L279)
2. I was not able to figure out how https://github.com/elm/elm-lang.org
   deals with the issue.

Also, both answers to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544763/how-to-create-spa-with-elm-0-19) suggest using `Cmd.map` without second thoughts.

**Is Cmd.map the "right" way to split a single page application in modules ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think sometimes you just have to do what's right *for you*. I used the `Cmd.map`/`Sub.map`/`Html.map` approach for an application I wrote that had 3 "pages" - Initializing, Editing and Reporting.

I wanted to make each of these pages its own module as they were relatively complicated, each had a fair number of messages that are only relevant to each page, and it's easier to reason about each page independently in its own context.

The downside is that the compiler won't prevent you from receiving the wrong message for a given page, leading to a runtime error (e.g., if the application receives an `Editing.Save` when it is in the `Reporting` page, what is the correct behavior? For my specific implementation, I just log it to the console and move on - this was good enough for me (and it never happened anyway); Other options I've considered include displaying a nasty error page to indicate that something horrible has happened - a BSOD if you will; Or to simply reset/reinitialize the entire application).

Comment: About that problem of receiving the wrong message  for a given page: you can avoid this. In your update function, instead of matching solely against your Msg variants, you can match against pairs (Msg, Page) so that a message is processed only if the current page in your main model is of a particular variant.

Comment: And what do you do if the pairs don't match?

Comment: You write your update function to handle all the pairs that match, and then at the end you have a catchall pattern to handle the numerous possible pairs that don't match. What I mean is something like this: https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-spa-example/blob/master/src/Main.elm#L207

Comment: In other words (this is from my answer):
"For my specific implementation, I just log it to the console and move on - this was good enough for me (and it never happened anyway); Other options I've considered include displaying a nasty error page to indicate that something horrible has happened - a BSOD if you will; Or to simply reset/reinitialize the entire application)."?

Comment: But, "Runtime error" and "something horrible has happened" made it sound like a serious problem. If your application is well architectured, a message that comes from a page that is no longer the active view should be safely discarded. If it can't be safely discarded, that means that message didn't really belong to that page in particular, it should belong to the top level application.

Comment: By the way, I realize that your message is 18 months old and so you probably had time to figure these things out. I'm writing for people who might be newer to Elm and who read that topic.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use the **effect pattern** as described extensively in [this discourse post](https://discourse.elm-lang.org/t/realworld-example-app-architected-with-the-effect-pattern/5753/9).

The core of this approach is that :

> The extended Effect pattern used in this application consists in definining an [Effect](https://elm-doc-preview.netlify.app/Effect?repo=dmy%2Felm-realworld-example-app#Effect) custom type that can represent all the effects that init and update functions want to produce.

And the main benefits :

> 1. All the effects are defined in a single [Effect](https://elm-doc-preview.netlify.app/Effect?repo=dmy%2Felm-realworld-example-app#Effect) module, which acts as an internal API for the whole application that is guaranteed to list every possible effect.
> 2. Effects can be inspected and tested, not like Cmd values. This allows to test all the application effects, including simulated HTTP requests.
> 3. Effects can represent a modification of top level model data, like the Session 3 when logging in 3, or the current page when an URL change is wanted by a subpage update function.
> 4. All the update functions keep a clean and concise Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Effect Msg ) 2 signature.
> 5. Because Effect values carry the minimum information required, some parameters like the Browser.Navigation.key are needed only in the effects perform 3 function, which frees the developer from passing them to functions all over the application.
> 6. A single NoOp or Ignored String 25 can be used for the whole application.

Comment: Note that this Effect pattern also use [Effect.map](https://github.com/dmy/elm-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/Main.elm#L152), and [that](https://elm-doc-preview.netlify.app/Effect?repo=dmy%2Felm-realworld-example-app&version=master#map) is just like [Cmd.map](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Platform-Cmd#map)…